# How to use SQL to search for a value?

Tags: android

I'm trying to learn how to use database in Android and so far I have learned how to fetch all rows of data in the table, but I'm not sure how I'm going to use a SQL query to search for a value that is equal to the string value I pass to the method below?

I wonder if someone could add some simple code how to query the database with SQL in my code? Preciate the help! Thanks!

Something like this: `String query = "Select * from DB_TABLE where TABLE_IMAGE_PATH = filePath";`

```
// Read from database
public String readContacts(String filePath){

    String[] columns = new String[]{TABLE_ID, TABLE_IMAGE_PATH, TABLE_CONTACT_NAME, TABLE_CONTACT_NUMBER, TABLE_CONTACT_ADDRESS};
    Cursor c = db.query(DB_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    int id = c.getColumnIndex(TABLE_ID);
    int imagePath = c.getColumnIndex(TABLE_IMAGE_PATH);
    int name = c.getColumnIndex(TABLE_CONTACT_NAME);
    int number = c.getColumnIndex(TABLE_CONTACT_NUMBER);
    int address = c.getColumnIndex(TABLE_CONTACT_ADDRESS);

    String result = "";

    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){ 
    result = result + c.getString(id) + " " + c.getString(imagePath) + " " + c.getString(name) + " " + c.getString(number) + " " + c.getString(address);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search Query

its for exact string

```
String query = "Select * from DB_TABLE where TABLE_IMAGE_PATH  like  '"+filePath+"';
```

if value contains your string

```
String query = "Select * from DB_TABLE where TABLE_IMAGE_PATH  like  '%"+filePath+"%';
```

if value needs from last

```
String query = "Select * from DB_TABLE where TABLE_IMAGE_PATH  like  '%"+filePath+"';
```

if value needs from first

```
String query = "Select * from DB_TABLE where TABLE_IMAGE_PATH  like  '"+filePath+"%';
```

put these

```
SQLiteDatabase dbR = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur = dbR.rawQuery("query", null);
            return cur
```

using this cursor you can get value.

Comment: Nice! But how do I handle the return value if there are more than one TABLE_IMAGE_PATH that is equal to the filePath?

Comment: manage the cursor and set it in list and check which one you needs... how filepath should same for two tables? tell clearly what you need brother

Answer (score 1):

you can do that easily by modifying your query code to:

```
        String[] columns = new String[]{TABLE_ID, TABLE_IMAGE_PATH, TABLE_CONTACT_NAME,   TABLE_CONTACT_NUMBER, TABLE_CONTACT_ADDRESS};

        Cursor cursor = db.query(ANSWERS_TABLE,
            columns,
            columns[1] + " = ?", new String[]{filePath}, null, null, null);
```

Take a look here : [SQLiteDataBase Query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)